# Problema com gets e fgets

Tags: c

Estou tendo problemas com a função gets e fgets...

Sempre quando as uso, o programa pula a entrada, ou seja o usuário não consegue digitar a *string*, mas só dá certo com *scanf*, só que preciso usar a gets ou fgets. Já usei a função `getchar()`; sempre que uso até deixa eu digitar, mas acaba repetindo, dizendo para gravar outro de novo e de novo e de novo...

Abaixo está o código:

```
int main()
{

    char s1[20];
    char s2[20];
    int escolha = 1;

    printf("*****************************\n");
    printf("*Menu de opções para strings*\n");
    printf("*****************************\n\n");
    printf("Primeiro informe seu nome por favor: ");
    gets(s1);

    do
    {
        printf("\n(1) Quer saber o tamanho de seu nome?\n");
        printf("(2) Que tal comparar seu nome com outro nome?\n");
        printf("(3) Quer unir seu nome com outro nome?\n");
        printf("(4) O que acha de seu nome invertido?\n");
        printf("(5) Quer saber quantas vezes a mesma letra aparece em seu nome?\n");
        scanf("%d", &escolha);
        system("cls");

        switch(escolha)
        {

        case 1:
            printf("A quantidade de caracters de seu nome é: %d", strlen(s1));
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("Digite um novo nome para comparar: ");
            fgets(s2, 20, stdin);
            break;

        default:
            printf("Opção inválida");
        }

    } while(escolha);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `gets` é considerado obsoleto, inseguro, feio e mal visto. Não use ele. No máximo use `fgets` passando `stdin` como argumento

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sugiro utilizar sempre `fgets`, uma vez que é algo que já está a utilizar, e garante que o seu programa nunca está susceptivel a [*Buffer Overflows*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transbordamento_de_dados).

Mesmo quando tem que ler um inteiro como no caso a `opcao`, pode na mesma ler o conteúdo como string para um buffer temporário de tamanho definido por si e interpretar o seu inteiro quer com [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) ou mesmo [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/):

```
char buff[20];
fgets(buff, 20, stdin);
sscanf(buff, "%d", &escolha);
```

Repare que o `sscanf` funciona como o `scanf` mas partindo de uma string em vez da stream de input.

Utilizando `fgets` e `sscanf`, o seu programa fica assim:

```
char s1[20];
char s2[20];
char buff[20]; //buffer de leituras
int escolha = 1;

printf("*****************************\n");
printf("*Menu de opções para strings*\n");
printf("*****************************\n\n");
printf("Primeiro informe seu nome por favor: ");
fgets(s1,20,stdin);
s1[strlen(s1)-1] = '\0'; //remover o \n que ficou da leitura com fgets

do {
    printf("\n(1) Quer saber o tamanho de seu nome?\n");
    printf("(2) Que tal comparar seu nome com outro nome?\n");
    printf("(3) Quer unir seu nome com outro nome?\n");
    printf("(4) O que acha de seu nome invertido?\n");
    printf("(5) Quer saber quantas vezes a mesma letra aparece em seu nome?\n");
    fgets(buff, 20, stdin); //agora fgets
    sscanf(buff, "%d", &escolha); //leitura do numero com sscanf
    system("cls");

    switch(escolha) {
    case 1:
        printf("A quantidade de caracters de seu nome é: %d", strlen(s1));
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Digite um novo nome para comparar: ");
        fgets(s2, 20, stdin);
        s2[strlen(s2)-1] = '\0'; //remover o \n também
        break;
    default:
        printf("Opção inválida");
    }

} while(escolha);
```

Pode se quiser abstrair a lógica de leitura para uma função de forma a simplificar as suas várias utilizações:

```
void lerString(char *stringLida){
    fgets(stringLida, 20, stdin);
    stringLida[strlen(stringLida)-1] = '\0';
}
```

Que utilizaria assim:

```
lerString(s1);
```

[Veja o código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/IYAocR)

Comment: Muito bakana, já tinha resolvido, mas dessa forma é bem mais profissional!!! obrigado!!!

Comment: Sabia que você tinha uma resposta dizendo se o `fgets` retornava a quebra de linha ou não. E de fato retorna. Salvou a resposta que estou escrevendo

Answer (score -1):

Não seria o caso de usar fflush(stdin) depois das seguintes linhas?

```js
gets(s1);
fflush(stdin);

scanf("%d", & escolha);
fflush(stdin);

fgets(s2, 20, stdin);
fflush(stdin);
```

Comment: Eu consegui resolver o problema, mas obrigado mesmo assim, na verdade era quase isso que vc citou, só que eu tive de colocar o fflush(stdin); antes do gets!!! quando colocava depois do gets dava erro. na minha humilde opinião acho que o problema é a caso de estar usando uma switch, talvez o enter que eu dava ao escolher uma opção ficava armazenado no buffer...

Comment: Legal! Deve ser mesmo, essa questão de lixo no Buffer é complicado rsr... Já sofri muito com isso, principalmente com o do while...

Comment: `fflush()` não deve ser usada para limpar buffers de entrada, no caso `stdin`, e `gets()` não deve ser utilizada porque não limita adequadamente a quantidade de caracteres que o usuário pode inserir.