# Leitura de Strings de Struct com scanf Dando Errado

Tags: c, string, arquivo, struct

Bom galera, estou desenvolvendo um código em C que realiza cadastro de dados em arquivos. Porém, estou com um problema na função **cadastrarCliente**, a qual vocês verão abaixo entre os códigos.

Struct do cliente:

```
typedef struct
{
        int idCliente;
        char nome[NOME_TAM_MAX];
        char CPF[16];
        char endereco[ENDERECO_TAM_MAX];    
}Cliente;
```

Macros:

```
#define NOME_TAM_MAX 51
#define ENDERECO_TAM_MAX 101
```

Função **cadastrarCliente**:

```
void cadastrarCliente (void)
{
        Cliente *newCliente = (Cliente *) malloc(sizeof(Cliente));
        if (!newCliente)
        {
                printf("ERRO DE MEMORIA!!!\n");
                exit(-1);
        }
        else
        {
                printf("\n--- PRENCHA OS DADOS DE CADASTRO DO CLIENTE ---\n\n");
                printf("Digite o ID do cliente: ");
                scanf(" %d", &newCliente->idCliente);
                printf("Digite o nome do cliente: ");
                scanf(" %s", newCliente->nome);
                printf("Digite o CPF do cliente: ");
                scanf(" %s", newCliente->CPF);
                printf("Digite o endereco do cliente: ");
                scanf(" %s", newCliente->endereco);

                stream = fopen("cliente.txt", "w+b"); // stream é global
                if (!stream)
                {
                        fputs("ERRO AO TENTAR LER ARQUIVO!!!\n", stderr);
                        exit(-1);
                }
                else
                {
                        fwrite(newCliente, sizeof(Cliente), 1, stream);
                        fclose(stream);
                }
        }

        return;
}
```

O erro é o seguinte, após digitar o nome do cliente e apertar enter, todos os outros atributos são pulados (mostrando apenas o conteúdo dos printf) e a função chega ao fim. Inverti os campos, colocando o CPF primeiro e depois endereço, após ler o CPF, tudo ocorre bem sucedido, mas o erro se repete ao ler o endereço também.

Comment: O nome que está a colocar tem espaços ? Vale lembrar que `scanf("%s` lê apenas uma palavra, deixando as restantes na stream de input. Se quiser ler uma linha inteira troque por `scanf("%[^\n]`

Comment: Tem espaços sim, mas achei que este problema poderia ser resolvido dando um espaçamento dentro do scanf, tal como está no código. Tentei utilizar como sugeriu, mas não funciona.

Comment: Dê um exemplo do tipo input que esteja a ler, para ser possivel de dizer a forma apropriada de o ler

Comment: Yuri Coelho Rosario

Comment: Cada um desses seria colocado de cada vez separado por enter ? Ou a seperação seria pelas virgulas ? O seu código interpreta 1 numero seguido de 3 textos. Não vejo como isso possa encaixar no exemplo que deu

Comment: A separação seria através do enter, após o enter, passa pro próximo. No caso, a primeira entrada é um número qualquer, a segunda o nome completo, a terceira o CPF e a quarta o endereço completo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Começo por reiterar o que tinha já dito em comentário:

> Vale lembrar que `scanf("%s` lê apenas uma palavra, deixando as restantes na stream de input. Se quiser ler uma linha inteira troque por `scanf("%[^\n]`

No entanto este é o exemplo genérico. Olhando para o seu caso em particular, tem uma leitura de um inteiro antes, por isso vai ficar uma quebra de linha por ler após o primeiro número, que será aquela que é apanhada logo a seguir se fizer `scanf("%[^\n]`. A solução é simplesmente consumir essa quebra com um pequeno espaço:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]",
//     ^--aqui
```

Tendo isto em consideração poderia reescrever o seu código de leitura assim:

```
printf("Digite o ID do cliente: ");
scanf("%d", &newCliente->idCliente);
printf("Digite o nome do cliente: ");
scanf(" %[^\n]", newCliente->nome); //mais que uma palavra
printf("Digite o CPF do cliente: ");
scanf(" %s", newCliente->CPF); //uma palavra
printf("Digite o endereco do cliente: ");
scanf(" %[^\n]", newCliente->endereco); //mais que uma palavra
```

[Veja este exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/Lek9km)

Outra alternativa seria ler com [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) que até seria mais seguro, mas isso tem as suas implicações. Uma delas seria que o [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) deixa a quebra de linha lida dentro da string. Neste caso não a sugeri pois quando utiliza [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) regra geral é mais apropriado fazer todas as leituras com [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) e não intercalar com `scanf`, o que pode complicar um pouco.

Tem aqui outra resposta que dei que detalha a leitura com `fgets`: 
[problema-com-gets-e-fgets](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/258980/problema-com-gets-e-fgets/258989#258989)

Comment: Desta vez funcionou. Muito obrigado pela solução e pela explicação, Isac. Li a resposta em outro tópico sobre fgets e agora está tudo claro pra mim. Abraços!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar scanf("\n %s"), porque se não ele vai ler apenas uma string e deixar as outras para trás. E se o seu nome a inserir tiver espaços o scanf não amarzena, pois ela encerra a leitura no primeiro espaço ou seja barra \0, caso seja este seu problema experimente usar fgets.

Comment: Tentei como sugeriu, mas não funcionou. Achei que o fgets não lia do teclado, apenas de arquivos.

Answer (score 0):

Boa Noite Yuri, testei seu codigo e aparentemente consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma:

```
printf("\n--- PRENCHA OS DADOS DE CADASTRO DO CLIENTE ---\n\n");
    printf("Digite o ID do cliente: ");
    scanf(" %d", &newCliente->idCliente);

    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Digite o nome do cliente: ");
    fgets(newCliente->nome,51,stdin);

    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Digite o CPF do cliente: ");
    fgets(newCliente->CPF,16,stdin);

    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Digite o endereco do cliente: ");
    fgets(newCliente->endereco,101,stdin);
```

Utilizei o `fflush(stdin)` para limpar o buffer, evitando pular os campos que vem depois, alem disso foi possivel capturar as string pelo teclado utilizando o `fgets()`

Comment: Olá Rogi, boa noite. Não sabia que fgets lia do teclado, achava apenas que era pra ler de arquivo, que bom saber disso. Mas bem, a solução apresentada não funcionou, agora o campo de nome está sendo pulado após apresentar o ID.