# Linguagem C - Por que meu vetor de char está ficando com NULL nas primeiras posições após um scanf de outra variável

Tags: c

Ao executar o código abaixo, escolhendo a opcão `2` é digitado o nome `"Teste Nome"`, a struct `pessoas[i].nome` fica com o valor `Teste Nome\n\000` logo após o `fgets()`. Contudo, após o `scanf()` (que é utilizado para pontuar a struct `pessoas[i].idade`), a struct `pessoas[i].nome` fica com o valor `\000\000\000te Nome\n\000`

Por favor, alguém sabe me dizer onde eu errei? Não consigo achar de jeito nenhum o bug.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <conio.h> // para leitura do nome
#define MAX 1
#define MAX_NOME 50

struct pessoa{
    char idade;
    char nome[MAX_NOME];
};

void main(){
    
    short opcao;
    struct pessoa pessoas[MAX];
    int i;
    
    do {
        printf("\n2 - Carregar os dados manualmente\n");
        printf("6 - Exibir todas as pessoas\n");
        printf("0 - S A I R\nOpcao: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &opcao);
        
        switch(opcao) {
            case 2: // Carregar os dados manualmente
                for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
                    printf("Nome: ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    fgets(pessoas[i].nome, MAX_NOME, stdin);
                    printf("Idade: ");
                    scanf("%d", &pessoas[i].idade);
                    
                }
                
                break;
            case 6: //Exibir todas as pessoas
                for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
                    printf("Idade: %2d - Nome: %s\n", pessoas[i].idade, pessoas[i].nome);
                }
                
                break;
            case 0: //S A I R
                // Nao faz nada
                
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nOpcao invalida\n");
                
                break;
        }
        
    } while(opcao != 0);
    
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` gera comportamento indefinido, então [não é recomendado usar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209) (e mesmo se funcionasse, deveria ser chamado depois do `scanf`, não antes). Enfim, o problema é misturar `scanf` e `fgets`, dê uma olhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/258980/112052) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5240789). E por que idade é um `char` e não um `int`?

Comment: @hkotsubo obrigado pelas orientações. Li todos os links compartilhados. De fato, a variável idade estava com o tipo errado. Alterei para short. Contudo, mesmo com tudo isso o sistema não funcionava. Apesar da minha pergunta ter ganho um (-2), fiz muitas perguntas antes de vir aqui. O que resolveu o bug mesmo foi o scanf() que estava sendo utilizado erroneamente. Vou responder à minha própria pergunta para que outras pessoas possam ver algum dia.

Answer (score 1):

Como já apontado por @hkotsubo, foi necessário alterar o `char idade` para `short idade`. Além disso, o `scanf()` também estava [errado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types): . Ao ler uma variável do tipo `short`, devemos usar o parâmetro `"%hd"` e não o `"%d"` (voltado para `int`).

Comment: Eu não vejo muita vantagem em usar `short`, ainda mais em um programa pequeno como esse. Use `int` mesmo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24371078