# C++ Parte de Codigo sendo ignorado

Tags: c++

Olá, estou começando a aprender programação, com C++, mas me deparei com um erro. Quando executo o seguinte codigo o segundo bloco do int main() que é esse usando o gets() ao inves do cin é simplemente ignorado pelo compilador. Não da erro nenhum, mas ele nao pede pro usuario digitar nada e não imprime nada tbm por consequencia. Mas quando eu removo o primeiro bloco, que é o usando cin, o segundo passa a funcionar normalmente mesmo sem eu ter alterado nada nele.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>//pra poder usar o gets()
#include <stdlib.h>//pra poder usar o malloc()
using namespace std;


int main(){

cout<<"\n\nPrograma do jeito padrao\n\n";
char vnome[50];
cin>>vnome;
cout<<vnome<<"\n\n";
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //ESSA É A PARTE QUE ESTA DANDO ERRADO, MAS QUANDO REMOVO A DE CIMA ELA FUNCIONA NORMALMENTE.
cout<<"\n\nPrograma Usando gets \n\n";
char vnome1[50];
gets(vnome1);
cout<<vnome1<<"\n\n";

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cout<<"\n\nPrograma que usa o malloc() para fazer alocamento dinamico de memoria\n\n";
char *vnome2=(char *)malloc(sizeof(vnome2)+1);
gets(vnome2);
cout<<vnome2<<"\n\n";


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Quando substituo aquele cin lá no inicio por um gets() tbm aí todos passam a funcionar. Será que tem alguma regra de nao poder usar cin e gets no mesmo codigo ou algo assim? Se isso nao fizer nenhum sentido desculpem, realmente estou começando agora kkkk

Answer (score -1):

Programa para referência: [Godbolt(original)](https://godbolt.org/z/3r5zvj8Mx).

Para a primeira entrada do programa o usuário digita um nome, por exemplo, *Pedro*, e aperta <kbd>enter</kbd>, o que denota uma nova linha. Internamente essa nova linha é traduzida pelo caractere `\n`. Dessa forma, a entrada consiste em 6 caracteres: `P`, `e`, `d`, `r`, `o` e `\n`.

Na sequência, `cin` lê a entrada até um espaço ou uma nova linha, entretanto sem armazenar o espaço ou a nova linha. Ou seja, `cin` irá ler até o caractere `o` e deixar o caractere `\n` no buffer de entrada.
Com isso, ainda há informação no buffer de entrada a ser lida, que é o `\n` e é isso que o `gets` lê. Entretanto, diferente de `cin`, `gets` lê até uma nova linha e descarta essa nova linha. Portanto, `gets` armazena nada em `vnome1` e limpa o buffer de entrada. Por isso, quando é escrito o conteúdo de `vnome1` aparece nada.

Para corrigir isso poderia ser colocado um `cin.get` após `cin>>vnome;` que leria e descartaria a nova linha e, assim, limpando o buffer de entrada. Ou substituir `cin>>vnome;` por `cin.getline(vnome, 50)`.  Com isso, o programa produz o resultado esperado: [Godbolt (com cin.get)](https://godbolt.org/z/hb77a4v18).

Entretanto, é possível notar a existência de warnings no programa. Isso acontece porque a função `gets` não é considerada segura, podendo resultar em overflow e não deve ser usada. Mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/258989/238197) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

Por isso, a função `gets` foi removida do `C` a partir de `C11` e removida do `C++` a partir de `C++14`. Caso se tente executar o programa sob a *standard* `C++17` com a diretiva `-std=c++17` resultará em [erro](https://godbolt.org/z/dar1od9bf):

> error: use of undeclared identifier 'gets'

Portanto, `gets` deve ser substituído. Se o código for em `C`, `gets` pode ser substituído por `fgets`. Se o código for em `C++`, pode-se usar `getline`.

Isso nos leva à outra questão: não se deve entremear `C` com `C++`. Array de caracteres para representar strings e `fgets` são característicos da linguagem `C`. Entretanto, `cin` e `cout` são `C++`.

Portanto, em `C++` o código é:

```
cout << "Programa em C++\n";
string vnome;
getline(cin, vnome);
cout << vnome;
```

Uma vez que `vnome` foi declarado como `std::string` (e não mais como um array de caracteres), foi usado `getline` ao invés de `cin.getline`. Ambas realizam a leitura até o fim da linha e descartam o caracter `\n`. A diferença é que `getline` é usado com `std::string`, enquanto `cin.getline` é usado com C strings ([Ler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4872416/7838591))

Em `C`, o equivalente seria:

```
printf("Programa em C\n");
char vnome[50];
fgets(vnome, 50, stdin);
printf("%s", vnome);
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Poderia ser explicado, por favor, o motivo do downvote? Dessa forma, posso editar e melhorar a resposta. Muito obrigado.